# In CKEditor, how do I always turn scrollbars on?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

When editing inside CKEditor, I always want the scrollbars to be shown. Is there a way to override the CSS to always show the scrollbars, even if there's nothing lower filling it up?

Answer (score 4):

it should be achievable using CSS.

I have a tool using the CKEditor and I see the body tag of the iframe in which the content is edited has a class `.cke_show_borders`.

So you can do:

```
.cke_show_borders {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Or to have more detailed control over the vertical/horizontal scrollbars

```
.cke_show_borders {
    overflow-y: scroll; // vertical scrollbar
    overflow-x: scroll; // horizontal scrollbar
}
```

Comment: This doesnt work. in ie8, scrollbars are not always shown. (its only shown if height is larger than normal, but if height inside the editor doesn't read the end, scrollbars are not there)

Comment: It's more correct to say that it works, in chrome, in FF... but maybe not in IE8. Try setting the height to 100% or 101%.